# Can a school force me to use cloud services I don't agree to?

Tags: internet, privacy, spain

I am currently studying and my school only allows certain cloud services from a third-party for assignment submissions.

I do not agree to the TOS of such cloud services (cloud storage services) and don't want to create an account or use them.

Similar to this [question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/45826/can-my-school-force-me-to-use-applications-or-a-school-issued-computer-if-i-do-n), but the answers there are mostly focused on the OOP being underage.

I am over the legal age and reside in Spain.

What can I do to be able to hand the assignments without using the cloud services? Are they legally able to force me to use such platform?

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: They can't force you to use the platform, but that just means you can't turn in the assignments. Use the cloud service for school assignments only and move on with life.

Comment: Not related to the TOS issue, but both France & Germany [have had bans](https://www.techzine.eu/news/privacy-compliance/95012/france-bans-office-365-and-google-workspace-in-schools/) on school use of American cloud providers for GDPR reasons. These appear to be on the governments' own initiatives though, I imagine a lawsuit would be necessary to force the issue in other EU countries for now.

Comment: The reasons for refusing could be relevant. "They require me to identify using biometric data" probably would be a valid objection. "I do not like their LGTB policy do I am boycotting them" probably would not be.

Comment: You use the term 'school.' Are you still in the public school system, at a publicly funded university, or at a private school or university?

Comment: @SJuan76 it is a privacy concern. See my comment in "ohwilleke"'s answer for context.

Comment: @o.m. it is privately funded

Comment: @mad, and you are there volunarily?

Comment: @o.m. Does private funding and voluntary attendance relieve the school or cloud server from GDPR compliance?

Comment: @MichaelHall, no, but one can use clouds in a GDPR-compliant way. As DPenner pointed out, public schools in Germany are actually required to go *beyond* GDPR by the education administration. That was a political decision based on political pressures, while a private university would be under commercial pressures.

Comment: @o.m., Would the OP's claim that "*the TOS establishes that data can be shared with second and third parties for marketing purposes, including sending data outside of the EU*" be an example of using clouds in a GDPR compliant way?

Comment: @MichaelHall, depends on what the user consents to and how that is put in the TOS. Right now we have the summary from the OP in a comment to another answer. I'm not saying that what the university and their provider are doing is fine, but outrage is a bad counsel in matters like this. Starting a lawsuit against an university where one is enrolled is going to be stressful. A public awareness campaign among other students may be a better idea *if* the university is reliant on tuition fees, and *if* the other students are somewhat likely to worry about privacy, too.

Comment: @o.m., I don't see any outrage occurring, I see this more as due diligence to manage the privacy of your personal information.

Comment: @MichaelHall, if I were a student these days (which I am not), my main concern would be if that cloud service includes any plagiarism detection systems, and if the appeals process for the judgement of those AIs is outsourced to the lowest bidder. And also if submitted essays become training/comparison data. Much more than wirry about names and birthdates.

Comment: These are questions you should have asked while evaluating the school for your consideration.

Answer (score 5):

The school isn't really "forcing you" to do anything. It is simply stating that if you want to take a particular class then you have to follow the rules of that class. You can opt not to take the class or not to attend the school if you really feel strongly about it.

A student can be obligated to follow all sorts of requirements of an educational institution.

The size and color of the paper you use can be regulated. The length of your assignments can be regulated. The subjects you do your research on can be regulated. The file formats that electronic work can be submitted in can be regulated. The deadline for turning in work can be regulated. The color of ink you use can be regulated. You can be required to purchase supplies from protractors to special kinds of calculators to art supplies to graph paper to staples v. paper clips v. glue v. three hole punches to connect multiple page assignments. A professor can decide if you are going to dissect a frog, or a fish, or a worm, or do an online dissection.

Why would a cloud service be any different?

The professor has a practical need to receive assignments in a consistent way so that the professor doesn't have to deal with too many cloud formats and file formats to grade each assignment. The professor has a practical need to make a centralized choice for everyone in the class that is convenient for the professor, not you.

Every time that I have ever taught a class remotely (I used to be a professor serving students all over the world and still teach continuing education classes remotely multiple times a year), the institution always established a single online interface and technical standards for students and professors to follow, and there is no way I could easily have managed with several competing cloud service platforms to deal with (this is hell to deal with as a lawyer even with support staff, junior attorneys, and IT consults to help in the process).

If using a particular cloud service with a certain TOS somehow violates a particular legal right that you have, perhaps. But which rights?

The only plausible ones I can imagine is if the cloud service requires you to assign copyrights to original creative works to them to upload work to it (which is common for social media platforms but rare for cloud storage services to share data), or violates European GDPR regulations. But, even then, the school is probably within its rights to have you surrender copyrights for your homework assignments.

Honestly, it is very hard to see any legitimate concerns that a student could have about a cloud service used to upload homework assignments for a professor to review. And, you aren't being required to use that service for any other purpose. It isn't a "tie-in" arrangement to force you to use this service in your business or personal life because you are taking this class.

The bottom line is that usually, how classes in an educational environment are taught aren't up to you. Maybe there is some detail of the TOS that is concerning that could clarify your concern, but the starting point assumption is that this is a completely reasonable requirement.

Comment: The cloud service requires me to register using my full real name (it gets verified), ID, phone number, age and gender.

A few years ago, I was a victim of online identity theft and it got pretty serious, hence my personal need to keep that kind of information outside of public platforms.

Additionally, the TOS stablishes that data can be shared with second and third parties for marketing purposes, including sending data outside of the EU.

Comment: @mad, That last sentence would seem to violate GDPR, (based on the limited knowledge i have gleaned on this site).  Maybe that's a better question than the one you asked. (*Rather than insinuating you are being "forced" to do something*)

Comment: @MichaelHall the TOS state that data can be sent outside of the EU since the company's headquarters is there. Does that break GDPR?

Comment: @mad, you already said that, and I responded that *it would seem to*.  I don't know GDPR well enough to answer though, I would recommend that you ask a fresh question on the topic.

Comment: "requires me to register using my full real name (it gets verified), ID, phone number, age and gender." From the school's point of view, these are features and not bugs so that the person submitting assignments is verified to be the student in the class and can't claim that someone made up a bogus account and submitted assignments that way. IRL homework assignment submissions require the same things and all of the information is a matter of public record and easily obtained. Allowing sharing for marketing purposes is probably not a big enough barrier to make it legally objectionable.

Comment: @mad, does the cloud service NOT have a checkbox enabling you to opt out of receiving marketing material?  Most do... and given my limited knowledge of how stringent GDPR is I would be surprised if a company serving the EU wouldn't allow you this choice.

Comment: A school can have all sorts of rules, but I don't see why it should naturally be able to compel students to enter directly into commercial contracts with third parties. I mean, should the school be able to compel students to enter into a complicated contract with the stationery supplier, as a condition of being provided with schoolbooks? Most would hold that it is the school that should enter these contracts, not the students.

Comment: @Steve You are asking the wrong question. Everything that isn't forbidden by law is permitted. A school can do anything it isn't specifically forbidden by law from doing. "should the school be able to compel students to enter into a complicated contract with the stationery supplier, as a condition of being provided with schoolbooks?" No reason why it shouldn't be allowed to do that. The law doesn't have to expressly permit something for it to be allowed.

Comment: @ohwilleke, my point is that the equivalence you draw between students being required to following ordinary school rules (such as those governing conduct), and being required to enter into separate commercial contracts with organisations of the school's choosing, is a completely false one. And if anything not specifically prohibited is allowed, then it should seem possible for the student to refuse, *without the school being able to do anything about the refusal*, because I seriously doubt there are specific laws that enable schools to compel entry into these contracts. (1/2)

Comment: If there are such laws in your jurisdiction then it would be interesting to understand what those laws say, but in general I would expect the law only says as much as that the school itself is allowed to enter directly into contracts with suppliers and marshal resources that assist in the provision of its own service, but I wouldn't expect the law to say that the school has the power to compel students (or for minors, their parents) to enter into further arbitrary contracts. (2/2)

Comment: @Steve Schools have the right to form contracts. Those contracts can say anything you want. The law prohibits violating contracts and allows contracts to condition benefits on their performance. Your sense of what the law can and cannot require is upside down.

Comment: @ohwilleke, if the school is any kind of public institution then it is unlikely the relationship is even contractual in the first place. But signing a contract with a school is unlikely to grant the school the right to compel the learning party to enter into whatever further contracts the school pleases with whatever third parties the school pleases on whatever terms those third parties please. The analogy you draw with the school's typical power to set some behavioural rules, is absurd. Do you believe the courts enforce "contracts" that consist of "you will do whatever we say later"?

Comment: @Steve "But signing a contract with a school is unlikely to grant the school the right to compel the learning party to enter into whatever further contracts the school pleases with whatever third parties the school pleases on whatever terms those third parties please." If anything the opposite is true. It is very likely.

Comment: @ohwilleke, do we have any authority that such terms are generally enforceable then, including in ordinary consumer/standard form contracts? It seems likely that such terms would be litigated regularly.

Comment: @Steve Such terms are almost never litigated. They are not within any public policy exception except when it amounts to an anti-trust violation. The OP does not suggest anything that would constitute an anti-trust violation. Common examples include mediation and arbitration terms, terms requiring insurance in leases and other contracts, franchise agreements, construction contracts dictating specific suppliers, endorsement agreements, etc.

Comment: @ohwilleke, a term that purports to impose on one party, *any* additional obligations which the other may later decide, I would have thought is potentially void for uncertainty. A construction contract which dictates a specific supplier at the outset is the opposite of what we are discussing - the equivalent construction contract would be one where the price is fixed up front but the obligations are whatever the other party later says they are.